# Get Javascript modified source code with requests

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests

Apologies if this question has already been asked, But from my research there was no question regarding use of the requests in this case.

HTML page i'm trying to access is using Javascript, Many elements are created/added from different Javascript static files. Chrome's inspect element gives the final proper HTML, But requests.get only returns HTML which was not affected by any static files: `requests.get("https://website.com").text`

Is there any way to load the webpage HTML after Javascript was executed? I'm trying to avoid Selenium for it's slower performance.

Comment: You will need to execute the JS code in some headless driver to obtain the final HTML, there is no way of obtaining this in the requests library itself

Comment: You could also try sending a header pretending to be an older browser, as many websites cater to them with reduced scripts.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't avoid `Selenium` if you want to run js. Maybe you can use an ajax api ( inspect xhr traffic ) or 'reverse' the js. If you share the url i could a look.

Comment: @t.m.adam Unfortunately i can't share it because it requires specific session, I think i have found out necessary Javascript here: https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/javascript/economy.js?v=hDn61Hn5NkI8&l=english where elements are created, But i'm trying to get element information.

Comment: Wow, that's too much code! You may get lucky and find an ajax api ( inspect > network > xhr ) If not you'll have to use `Selenium` or `PyQt4` or  `dryscrape`

Comment: @t.m.adam Thanks, If you have experience with dryscrape, Is it more lightweight than Selenium? Selenium is extremely slow especially on Pythonanywhere.

Comment: Yes i know, it's the last option for me too. I've never used `dryscrape` ( i'm on windows ) but i've read it's a bit faster.

Comment: I was able to find something that might work for you...

https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/ultimate-guide-for-scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages/

Answer (score 0):

Using request you can only get the resource ('text/html' in your case) which the url specified.  To resolve all dependencies, try Jsdom package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom).

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm not using node.js, Is there any known alternative for python?